# JAVA modify date of String format

Tags: java, rest, xhtml

//Hello all,

So, I have method

```
public void init() {
        list = taskManager.getList();
        list.sort((object1, object2) -> ((String) object2.getProperties().get("bpm_startDate"))
        .compareTo((String) object1.getProperties().get("bpm_startDate")));
 }
```

This method sorts my list by the date, list gets filled from REST service, so date comes in a String format.

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg.date}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{task.properties.bpm_startDate.substring(0,16).replace('T','  ')}">
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

this is how I "cut-off" all the redundant part of date, before displaying it to the user.

Question is, how to add 3 hours to date ?

Comment: Damn.. all answers kinda gives what I needed.. Don't know which is the winner now :)

Comment: If they're all evenly suitable, I say hook up the person wit the least rep :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use java.util.Calendar and DateFormat

```
//Parse String for Date
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
Date myDate = format.parse(stringDate);

//Use Calendar to add 3 hours
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(myDate);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);

//Retransform date to String
String newDate= format.format(c.getTime());
```

Remember to replace "yyyy/MM/dd" with your actual format following the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert String date to Date using SimpleDateFormat like this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

For adding Hours(time)
Check Calendar class. It has add method (and some others) to allow time manipulation. Something like this should work.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(date); // sets calendar time/date
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); // adds one hour
cal.getTime(); // returns new date object, one hour in the future
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you check out the Joda-Time library. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Since I don't know the format your original date is stored in I can't provide the exact code you want, but you'll need to look at:

- DateTimeFormatter - to create a formatter for your strings to a date format. Something like ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withZoneUTC() should do the trick. See http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html
- DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime() - to convert the string to a DateTime
- DateTime.plusHours() - see http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusHours%28int%29